# Array modifier with curve is deforming mesh?

Tags: modifiers

This is simple, but I can't figure out why it's happening. I took a couple weeks off of Blender (still a beginner) and I've apparently forgotten a lot of stuff..

I'm trying to follow this guide on [how to duplicate an object along a curve](https://www.versluis.com/2019/07/duplicating-an-object-along-a-path-in-blender-2-8/), but no matter what I do, my mesh object gets deformed like crazy. In my example I was trying to duplicate a plain old cube along a circle curve. The only thing I changed was the scale of the circle curve.

Can someone tell me why it's not working as it is in the guide?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scale and apply the scale of a cuve, its vertices radius will change to the value before the scaling, here it looks like you've scaled up to 9.677. To bring the value back to 1, select all the vertices and type 1 in the N panel:

[image]

Comment: How strange... I thought applying the scale would take care of that already... Weird. Thanks moonboots!

Comment: yes a bit counter-intuitive but there must be a good reason (?)